# How to convert the below R code to python

Tags: python, r

Objective: To get the class/dtype of features from a dataframe and incorporate the data into a new data frame containing  features names as rows.
For clarity I am pasting the R code for it which I was able to crack

```
Variables<-as.data.frame(names(telecom))    ##Telecom original dataset-Incorporating columns names as dataframes in variable object

##If class integer it goes as CONT and if categorical then "CAT" into a new column "cont_cat" in Variable dataframe
for(i in 1:ncol(telecom))
{
  Variable$cont_cat[i]<-ifelse(class(telecom[,i])=="integer"|class(adult[,i])=="numeric","Cont","Cat")
}
```

The first part of it, I was able to crack in Python

```
Variables=pd.DataFrame(credit_data.columns, columns=["Features"])
```

However, I need help with second part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample solution. You will have to change the wanted category to your problem

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Variables['cont_cat'] = np.nan

wanted_categories = ["int64","object", "float64"] #change wanted datatypes to your scenario

for i in range(len(telecom.columns)):
    if telecom.iloc[:,i].dtypes in wanted_categories: 
        Variables.iloc[i,1] = "cat" #pandas iloc [row, index]
```